# Unit Testing Azure Functions with FastAPI and Python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, azure-functions, fastapi

I have the file structure:

> PROJECT
>
> - contract-metadata
>   -- **init**.py
>   -- test_function.py

this is my **init**.py:

```
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func
#from FastAPIApp import app  # Main API application
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
import fastapi
import os

app = fastapi.FastAPI()
client = CosmosClient.from_connection_string(os.environ["CONNECTIONSTRINGSETTING"])

database_name = "dmdb"
container_name = "DataContract"

database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
container = database.get_container_client(container_name)
logging.info(f"container: {container}")


@app.get("/marketplace/{V}")
async def get_data_by_version(V: str):
    logging.info("all data contracts are coming....")
    query = f''' SELECT c.name,c.version, c.Theme, c.title, c.description, udf.tsToDate(c._ts) as updated_at
                FROM c 
                WHERE c.version = '{V}'
                ORDER BY c._ts DESC
                OFFSET 0 LIMIT 20
               '''
 
    items = list(container.query_items(query, enable_cross_partition_query=True))
    logging.info(f"items: {items}")
    response_body = json.dumps(items)
    return func.HttpResponse(body=response_body, mimetype="application/json")


@app.get("/marketplace/{V}/themes")
async def get_existing_themes_by_version(V: str):
    query = f"SELECT c.Theme FROM c WHERE c.version = '{V}'"
    items = list(container.query_items(query, enable_cross_partition_query=True))
    unique_themes = list(set(item["Theme"] for item in items))
    response_body = json.dumps(unique_themes)
    return func.HttpResponse(body=response_body, mimetype="application/json")

@app.get("/marketplace/{V}/{id}")
async def get_data_by_version_and_id(V: str, id: str):
   
    query = f"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.version = '{V}' AND c.id = '{id}'"
    items = list(container.query_items(query, enable_cross_partition_query=True))
    
    if not items:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"No item with version '{V}' and id '{id}' was found",
            status_code=404
        )
    
    response_body = json.dumps(items[0])
    return func.HttpResponse(body=response_body, mimetype="application/json")





async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return await func.AsgiMiddleware(app).handle_async(req, context)
```

this is my test_func.py:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
import azure.functions as func
import unittest
import pytest
from __init__ import (
    app, main,
    get_data_by_version,
    get_existing_themes_by_version,
    get_data_by_version_and_id
)

# Unit tests
client = TestClient(app)
def test_get_data_by_version():
    expected_data = [
        {"name": "contract1", "version": "V1", "Theme": "Theme1", "title": "Title1", "description": "Description1"}
    ]
    response = client.get("/marketplace/V1")
    
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == expected_data

def test_get_existing_themes_by_version():
    expected_themes = ["Theme1", "Theme2"]
    response = client.get("/marketplace/V1/themes")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == expected_themes

def test_get_data_by_version_and_id():
    expected_data = {"name": "contract1", "version": "V1", "id": "123"}
    response = client.get("/marketplace/V1/123")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == expected_data
```

I could not import from **init** import (
app, main,
get_data_by_version,
get_existing_themes_by_version,
get_data_by_version_and_id
)

These functions and I could not import the pytest, neither. I installed but it did not work.

Could you regulate my test file according to my code?

Comment: You can make use of this code sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'CosmosTrigger1'))) here CosmosTrigger1 is the folder in which your init.py and test_func.py exist

import __init__

__init__. Refer this image - https://i.imgur.com/HV4RWU5.png to import the functions and methods from __init__.py to test_func.py

Comment: You can add the same package by running this dot net add command in your code editor or terminal - https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/9.3.3?_src=template same for this package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/2.2.5?_src=template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> I could not import from  **init**  import ( app, main, get_data_by_version, get_existing_themes_by_version, get_data_by_version_and_id ) These functions and I could not import the pytest, neither. I installed but it did not work.
> ```

In order to import the functions from **init**.py to test_func.py add this line of code in your test_func.py :-

```py
import sys
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
import azure.functions as func
import unittest
import pytest
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'CosmosTrigger1')))

import __init__

__init__.get_data_by_version 

__init__.get_existing_themes_by_version

__init__.app

__init__.main

__init__.get_data_by_version_and_id
```

Here CosmosTrigger1 is the name of the folder which contains **init.py** and test_func.py and the functions from **init**.py is imported successfully, Refer below:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: now i am getting another error.  test_function.py - KeyError: 'CosmosDBConnStr'

Comment: Is your CosmosDBConnStr set as environment variable

Comment: this is my local.setting.son file :  {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "CosmosDBConnStr": "************",
    "BlobConnStr": "***",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}            it is coming from here i am using it in my code

Comment: client = CosmosClient.from_connection_string(os.environ["CosmosDBConnStr"])
<frozen os>:679: in __getitem__
    ???
E   KeyError: 'CosmosDBConnStr'

Comment: It should work with client = CosmosClient.from_connection_string(os.environ["CosmosDBConnStr"]) try changing the python interpretor from venv to normal one in your vs code and run the code again? or try to add the connection string directly in CosmosClient.from_connection_string(<connection-string>) and test once?

Comment: I already added it and also I have mock data in my code, why we need this?

Comment: i checked again but i am getting still same error. what should i do?

Comment: I execute $venv ConnectionStrings =“” command in vscode terminal and the problem resolved, but tests are failed. How can I regulate it?